# MySQL Table Structure Best Practice Many to Many

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have 39 large tables of between 8,000 to 1,500,000 rows to partition data in MySQL4. Each table represents an origin airport code and the data within are the package holiday deals from each of these origins (140 columns).

I'm making an auto suggest field for hotel names but I would like to base this on package durations, package types and origins.

I have another table with just 3000 rows for all of the hotels so I would like to use this table for the auto suggest feature due to it's small size and speed.

Each hotel has many origins, package types and package durations.

My question is how should I populate this hotels table with all of the origins.
My only idea so far is to a delimited list for each of the package types, package durations and airport codes.

Example record:

```
hotel_name = Some Hotel
origin = YYC;YEG;YVR
duration = 04;05;06;07;09;10;14
package_Type = 03;04;09
```

And then use:

```
SELECT `hotel_name` from `hotels`
WHERE `hotel_name` LIKE '%$typed_text%' 
AND  `package_duration` LIKE '%09%' 
AND  `package_type` LIKE '%04%' 
AND  `origin` LIKE '%YEG%' 
ORDER BY `hotel_name`
```

Would this be the best way to tackle this kind of query of is there something else I should be doing?
Thanks

---

EDIT: I tried a couple of solutions and this one fit my data structure and queried within 0.001 seconds on 3000 hotels.

**It's by no means a recommended method as it breaks just about every rule there is in database query but here it is anyway**

Here's an example dump:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hotels` (
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `hotel_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `origins` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `package_types` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `package_durations` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `hotels`
--

INSERT INTO `hotels` (`id`, `hotel_name`, `origins`, `package_types`, `package_durations`) VALUES
(1, 'Bel Air Collection Resort & Spa Vallarta', 'YYC;YXX;YQQ;YEG;YLW;YUL;YQR;YYZ;YVR;YYJ;YWG;', '09;', '06;07;08;13;14;15;'),
(2, 'Grand Velas All Suites & Spa Resort, Riviera Maya', 'YYC;YXX;YQQ;YEG;YHM;YXU;YUL;YOW;YQB;YQR;YXE;YYZ;', '09;', '03;04;09;10;11;06;07;08;13;14;15;'),
(3, 'Barcelo Capella Beach Resort', 'YYC;YEG;YHZ;YUL;YOW;YYZ;YVR;YWG;', '09;', '06;07;08;13;14;15;'),
(4, 'Iberostar Cozumel', 'YYC;YBG;YYG;YEG;YFC;YHZ;YXU;YQM;YUL;YOW;YQB;', '09;', '06;07;08;13;14;15;'),
(5, 'Valentin Imperial Maya', 'YYC;YBG;YXX;YQQ;YEG;YHZ;YHM;YXU;YUL;', '09;', '06;07;08;03;04;09;10;11;13;14;15;');
```

And an example script to interrogate the table:

```
$data[n] = 'resort';  //auto suggest text
$data[t] = '9';       //package_type
$data[d] = '7;8;10';  //durations
$data[o] = 'YUL;YVR'; //origins

//Split origins
foreach(explode(';',$data[o]) as $ori)
{
    $origin_sql[] = "`origins` LIKE '%".str_pad(mysql_real_escape_string($ori), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).";%'";
}
$data[o] = "(".implode(' OR ',$origin_sql).")";

//Split durations 
foreach(explode(';',$data[d]) as $dur)
{
    $duration_sql[] = "`package_durations` LIKE '%".str_pad(mysql_real_escape_string($dur), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).";%'";
}
$data[d] = "(".implode(' OR ',$duration_sql).")";

if($data[n]!=''&&$data[o]!=''&&$data[t]!=''&&$data[d]!='')
{
    $n = str_pad(mysql_real_escape_string($data[n]), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $t = str_pad(mysql_real_escape_string($data[t]), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

    $s = "SELECT `hotel_name` FROM `backend_hotels` WHERE
    `hotel_name` LIKE '%".$n."%' AND 
    `package_types` LIKE '%".$t.";%' AND 
    ".$data[o]." AND
    ".$data[d]."
     ORDER BY `hotel_name` ASC;";
    if($q = mysql_query($s))
    {
        while($r=mysql_fetch_array($q,MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            $names[] = $r[hotel_name];
        }
        echo json_encode($names);
    }
}
```

To produce a query like:

```
SELECT `hotel_name`
FROM `hotels`
WHERE `hotel_name` LIKE '%resort%'
AND `package_types` LIKE '%09;%'
AND (
  `origins` LIKE '%YUL;%'
   OR `origins` LIKE '%YVR;%'
)
AND (
  `package_durations` LIKE '%07;%'
  OR `package_durations` LIKE '%08;%'
  OR `package_durations` LIKE '%10;%'
)
ORDER BY `hotel_name` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

**Like I mentioned this approach wouldn't be good for large data sets at all due to the slow speed of the LIKE query. This just happened to be easier to implement with 11 million package deals and 3000 hotels, and I just like to show what I did end up implementing in case it can be a help to anyone else**

Comment: may I heavily suggest you do '$typed_text%' instead since having it know the start of the search will greatly improve performance.

Comment: Thanks hackartist but that wouldn't match the middle of a name.
This is needed if someone was searching for all Marriott hotels
New York Marriott
Chicago Marriott 
Etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i would typically do is to break the relationship into parts:

> Each **hotel** has many **origins**, **package types** and **package durations**.

so you have:

- hotels
- origins
- package types
- package durations

now, if you think of it, **Hotels** is the main subject here and so it should be the item *to be tagged* (imagine facebook)

now, how do you "tag"? let's take origins. each hotel can have many origins, origins may have a lot of hotels. what you do now is to make a "junction table". i'll try drawing it here:

```
    Hotels      Hotels_Origin    Origin
1. Marriott          1-1       1. US
2. Waterfront        1-2       2. UAE
                     2-1
```

you see that a "tag" is nothing more than a "relationship" based on a junction. in this example, Marriott is tagged on both locations, Waterfront tagged with US. to get this query, you have to use "LEFT JOIN"

> The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table_name1), even if there are no matches in the right table (table_name2). (*W3schools*) - *it's just an explanation.*

the left join ensures that we get what we want based on the LEFT side of the argument:

```
SELECT hotels.name, origin.name FROM hotels
LEFT JOIN hotels_origin ON hotels.id = hotels_origin.id  //match the hotel to junction
LEFT JOIN hotels_origin ON hotels_origin.id = origin.id  //match junction to origins
WHERE hotel.id=1                                        //get hoted by id
```

the following returns the hotel with ID of 1 (Marriott):

```
hotels.name    origin.name
Marriott       US
Marriott       UAE
```

now with that said, you do the same for all the other tables.

an advantages to this method is

- there will be NO duplicates in the table. you can have one origin tagged on to many hotels with just the junction table relationships modified.
- this method is much more scalable and maintainable
- easier look-up, especially for auto-suggest (since there are no duplicates)
- you don't modify the records, just the relationship.

  the problem now is.. you need to remodel the database.

Comment: Thank you Joseph, this answers my question extremely well.

Answer (score 1):

No, this would not be the best way.  You don't want to use delimited lists in a column.  What you want is a junction table to represent each relationship. You want to design your database in third normal form.

In your example above, you need to break each many to many relationship into its own table.  So the hotel table will have a primary key (id), name, etc.  Then have a HotelToOrigin table, with each row holding a hotel_id and origin_id.  Then a HotelToDuration table would be similar, hotel_id and duration_id.  And so forth.  Its a bit more complex to setup, but this makes it the most easy and accurate to query the database.  If you use LIKE statements with the table structure you mentioned above, if you ever have a package type of '044' you'll get that in your query not just '04'.  So your query will be inaccurate.

Comment: There's a finite number of package types and package durations and I'll be left padding each number with zeros to prevent any incorrect results

Comment: Thats fine, but it is still a really bad practice to put delimited values in a column.  It violates 3nf and if you design the data schema they way I mentioned, you wont have to keep up with that.  I would also recommend that you do not assign the ID's for hotels, packages, durations, etc. yourself.  Use an identity field that will autonumber them or a GUID that will randomly generate an ID.  Your IDs (primary keys and foreign keys) should be machine generated never changed, not human generated.